# Rails: Joining multiple temp fields before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

So basically I have a Book model that contains information like

- book title (string)
- author (string)
- description (text)
- etc.

Now on the front end I added the capability of dynamically adding more author fields. In the form I named it `book[coauthor]`, so if I add a second author, I'd have a field `book[coauthor][name_0]`.

What I'd like to achieve is combine `book[author]` and all `book[coauthor][name_i]` to one big string and separate each name with `,`. (i.e. so with `book[author]` being "Alice" and `book[coauthor][name_0]` being "Bob" I should get "Alice,Bob" saved in `book[author]` in DB)

**First Question**: At this point is it better to do it with Javascript or with Rails (in controller)?

**Second Questiion**: Currently I'm doing it in the Rails controller but got `Can't mass-assign protected attribute 'coauthor'`. However I don't want to make it a real attribute since  all I need is some processing before saving all the information to the `author` field. What should I do?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is a bit loaded, and you might get some heated disagreements but the way I look at it is this. Not everybody runs with Javascript enabled, so I make sure I have a way to do everything through Rails myself.

In this case, it's actually quite easy.

The first thing I recommend is to not send the coauthors as part of the `params[:book]`. Instead, send them separately as a `params[:coauthors]`. Then in your controller you can do this:

```
@book = Book.new(params[:book])
@book.author = ([@book.author] + [params[:coauthors]]).join(",")
@book.save
```

Actually, it may be better to update params[:book][:author] since that would work for both `create` and `update`. Either way, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To the first question: I don't see any compelling reason to one over the other. JavaScript might provide a bit more ability to validate/fix formatting in this field in 'real time', but I'm not sure that's particularly important.

To the second question: You don't need to make something a real attribute in order to make it accessible. You've presumably created `coauthor` as a virtual attribute using `attr_accessor`, but this doesn't automatically add it to the mass-assignment whitelist. To do that, also add it to your `attr_accessible` list.